# How to detect when user dismisses an interstitial Ad in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, gadinterstitial

I'm showing `GADInterstitialAd` in my iOS app using present in Swift. Below is the code I'm using to show ad.

```
func showAd() {
    if self.interstitialAd.isReady {
        self.interstitialAd.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
}
```

I'm running a timer on screen which I want to pause and resume once the ad is dismissed off the screen. Can anybody tell me how to implement this? I checked `interstitialWillDismissScreen` but seems like for that I need to have my custom class derived from `GADInterstitialDelegate`. As of now I'm directly using `var interstitialAd: GADInterstitial!` and I'm wondering if there is any way I can just check when Ad is on and off the screen?

Comment: you need to have your class delegate GADInterstitialDelegate , there is no alternative with my knowledge. Is there reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: I realized it after Daniel's comment below. I think I misunderstood the concept but it became fairly easy after Daniel's sample code from below. Thanks for your comment @AmodGokhale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `GADInterstitialDelegate` in your class. There is no other way to check if the ad is on screen.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Setup interstitial here
        // Set its delegate
        interstitial.delegate = self
    }

    func interstitialWillPresentScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        print("Ad presented")
    }

    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        // Send another GADRequest here
        print("Ad dismissed")
    }
}
```